# why does a child window hide when I hide the parent window

Tags: java, swing, window, jdialog

In the below program when I make a call to hide the parent window and then check the status of child window. I can see that the child window also goes off. Why it that?

Is this a feature that whenever we hide a parent window then all child window also gets hidden.

I know it seems obvious but is it documented somewhere?

The definition of setVisible() only says that :
**if true, makes the Dialog visible, otherwise hides the Dialog. If the dialog and/or its owner are not yet displayable, both are made displayable. The dialog will be validated prior to being made visible.** -> it only says about the owner dialog but nothing about a child dialog.

Program :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 class MyDialogParent extends JDialog {

     MyDialogParent ()
    {
        super(null,ModalityType.MODELESS);

    //    super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setVisible(false);


        // Disable Alt-F4 and any other close key sequences (MMSmk90468).
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

     @Override
        public void setVisible(boolean b)
        {
         System.out.println("parent visiblity its overridden method b : "+b);
            super.setVisible(b);
        }

}

 class MyDialogChild extends JDialog {

     MyDialogChild (Window parent)
        {
         super(parent,ModalityType.MODELESS);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);


        }

     @Override
        public void setVisible(boolean b)
        {
         System.out.println("child visibility in its overridden method  b : "+b);

            super.setVisible(b);

        }
    }


public class MyDialogs {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyDialogParent parent=new MyDialogParent();
        parent.setSize(400, 400);
        System.out.println("parent.isVISIBLE : "+parent.isVisible());

        parent.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("parent.isVISIBLE a : "+parent.isVisible());
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");

        MyDialogChild child=new MyDialogChild(parent);
        child.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        child.setSize(300, 300);
        child.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        child.add(new JPanel());
        System.out.println("child.isVISIBLE : "+child.isVisible());
        child.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("child.isVISIBLE a : "+child.isVisible());

        System.out.println("5");
        System.out.println("6");
        System.out.println("parent.isVISIBLE : "+parent.isVisible());
        System.out.println("child.isVISIBLE : "+child.isVisible());
        parent.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("parent.isVISIBLE a : "+parent.isVisible());
        System.out.println("child.isVISIBLE a : "+child.isVisible());
    //  child.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's likely OS specific, but if you have a child dialog, it's not unreasonable to think that if the parent is hidden, then the context of the child dialog could be "lost" and is then hidden as well

Comment: no another idea (by comparing your last question about), works for me, just to required to play with setVisible(isVisible)

Comment: When creating the child dialog try 
`super(null,ModalityType.MODELESS);`

Comment: @FredK could you please explain what you mean. That would at least help in understanding your view point